# Integrating a SELECT in an already written SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have been given an SQL query which is pretty much above my level of expertise and I can't figure out how to add a new column as the output when the query is ran.

```
    SELECT ProductId,Name as Provider FROM (
SELECT  COALESCE(ByExternalImageId.ProductId,EANProductImage.ProductId) as ProductId, COALESCE(ByExternalImageId.ProductImageProviderId,EANProductImage.ProductImageProviderId) as ProductImageProviderId FROM Product
                               LEFT JOIN
                               (
                               SELECT Product.Id as ProductId,MIN(EANProductImage.ProductImageProviderId) as ProductImageProviderId FROM Product
                                   INNER JOIN ProductImage as EANProductImage ON
                                       EANProductImage.ExternalImageId = Product.EAN
                                   INNER JOIN ProductImageAngle as EANProductImageAngle ON
                                       EANProductImage.AngleId = EANProductImageAngle.Id
                                   WHERE HasImage=1
                                   GROUP BY Product.Id
                               ) as EANProductImage ON
                                   EANProductImage.ProductId = Product.Id
                               LEFT JOIN (
                               SELECT top 1 Product.Id as ProductId,MIN(ExternalProductImage.ProductImageProviderId) as ProductImageProviderId FROM Product
                                   INNER JOIN ProductImage as ExternalProductImage ON
                                       ExternalProductImage.ExternalImageId  = Product.ExternalImageId
                                   INNER JOIN ProductImageAngle as ExternalProductImageAngle ON
                                       ExternalProductImage.AngleId = ExternalProductImageAngle.Id
                                   WHERE HasImage=1
                                   GROUP BY Product.Id
                               ) as ByExternalImageId ON
                                   ByExternalImageId.ProductId = Product.Id
                                   WHERE COALESCE(ByExternalImageId.ProductImageProviderId,EANProductImage.ProductImageProviderId) IS NOT NULL                                
                                  ) as images INNER JOIN ProductImageProvider ON ProductImageProvider.Id = images.ProductImageProviderId where Name='GS1'
```

Right, so above is the query that I have been given. This outputs the following:

[image]

What I couldn't figure out is how can I also select column `[Name]` from `dbo.Product` and join it with the current output on `ProductId`? I know the basic syntax needed to do this, but I don't know where I should **integrate** it with the code above.

So what I would need is something like: `SELECT Product.Name FROM Product inner join [the query above]`, eventually the output being like:

```
ProductId          Provider          Name
....               ....              ....
```

I do realize how stupid this question sounds, but I've tried numerous ways on how to integrate this small thing into the query presented above. My problem is that I do not understand the code fully (especially because it was not written by me) in order to actually put it into practice.

Comment: `SELECT  COALESCE(ByExternalImageId.ProductId,EANProductImage.ProductId) as ProductId, COALESCE(ByExternalImageId.ProductImageProviderId,EANProductImage.ProductImageProviderId) as ProductImageProviderId, Name FROM Product`
I would expect...try that, at least. It doesn't look like you'd want it from any of the subqueries (although, without seeing the table data which produces the current result, it's never easy to be 100% certain).

Comment: To be honest the formatting of this query is the biggest struggle. Properly aligning everything and using aliases would go a LONG way to making this more manageable. As it sits right now it is a wall of text which makes it far more difficult to decipher.

Comment: @ADyson After doing that, it tells me that `Column Name is ambiguous`, even after I specified `Product.Name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close you have to encapsulate the entire inner query with parens.

**Using a Sub-Query**

```
SELECT Product.Name,SubqueryAlias.*  FROM Product inner join 
(
    [the query above]
)
AS SubqueryAlias ON SubqueryAlias.ProductID=Product.ProductID
```

**Using a CTE**

```
;WITH As MyCTE
(
     [the query above]
)
SELECT Product.Name, M.Provider FROM Product 
inner join MyCTE M ON M.ProductID=Product.ProductID
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The first code is working fine, however, after running it I only get the Product.Name, without the other 2 columns. As for the second code, I am getting the exception `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.`. Could you provide me a fix for these issues, please?

Comment: I added SubqueryAlias.*. This will return all fields of the inner query along with the product name field from the outer, however, you could changed it to return only he desired fields such as SubqueryAlias.Provider

Answer (score 1):

You can remove one layer of subselect to get the answer you want, it should be noted that Provider can only ever be 'GS1' as this is what your query filters on. I have removed any columns or joins which aren't used in your top query:

```
 SELECT  COALESCE(ByExternalImageId.ProductId,EANProductImage.ProductId) as ProductId, 
          Product.Name As Provider
  FROM Product
  LEFT JOIN
     (
        SELECT Product.Id as ProductId,
               MIN(EANProductImage.ProductImageProviderId) as ProductImageProviderId 
        FROM Product
        INNER JOIN ProductImage as EANProductImage 
             ON  EANProductImage.ExternalImageId = Product.EAN
        INNER JOIN ProductImageAngle as EANProductImageAngle 
             ON  EANProductImage.AngleId = EANProductImageAngle.Id
        WHERE HasImage=1
        GROUP BY Product.Id
      ) as EANProductImage 
          ON  EANProductImage.ProductId = Product.Id
      LEFT JOIN 
         (
            SELECT top 1 Product.Id as ProductId,
                   MIN(ExternalProductImage.ProductImageProviderId) as ProductImageProviderId 
            FROM Product
            INNER JOIN ProductImage as ExternalProductImage 
                 ON  ExternalProductImage.ExternalImageId  = Product.ExternalImageId
            INNER JOIN ProductImageAngle as ExternalProductImageAngle 
                 ON  ExternalProductImage.AngleId = ExternalProductImageAngle.Id
            WHERE HasImage=1
            GROUP BY Product.Id
          ) as ByExternalImageId 
              ON  ByExternalImageId.ProductId = Product.Id
    WHERE COALESCE(ByExternalImageId.ProductImageProviderId,EANProductImage.ProductImageProviderId) IS NOT NULL AND
          Product.Name='GS1'
```