# Using a sub-query does not allow me to access a certain column

Tags: sql, sql-server

This question is related to a previous question asked here: [Integrating a SELECT in an already written SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58270019/integrating-a-select-in-an-already-written-sql-query)

After sorting out the above problem, I was faced with a **VERY** similar one, yet quite different. So right now I have the following code:

```
SELECT ProductImage.Brandname, ProductImage.Description ,SubqueryAlias.*  FROM ProductImage inner join
(
SELECT Product.Name, Product.Description ,SubqueryAlias.*  FROM Product inner join
(
-- The original query starts --
SELECT ProductId,Name as Provider FROM (
SELECT  COALESCE(ByExternalImageId.ProductId,EANProductImage.ProductId) as ProductId, COALESCE(ByExternalImageId.ProductImageProviderId,EANProductImage.ProductImageProviderId) as ProductImageProviderId FROM Product
                              LEFT JOIN
                              (
                              SELECT Product.Id as ProductId,MIN(EANProductImage.ProductImageProviderId) as ProductImageProviderId FROM Product
                                  INNER JOIN ProductImage as EANProductImage ON
                                      EANProductImage.ExternalImageId = Product.EAN
                                  INNER JOIN ProductImageAngle as EANProductImageAngle ON
                                      EANProductImage.AngleId = EANProductImageAngle.Id
                                  WHERE HasImage=1
                                  GROUP BY Product.Id
                              ) as EANProductImage ON
                                  EANProductImage.ProductId = Product.Id
                              LEFT JOIN (
                              SELECT top 1 Product.Id as ProductId,MIN(ExternalProductImage.ProductImageProviderId) as ProductImageProviderId FROM Product
                                  INNER JOIN ProductImage as ExternalProductImage ON
                                      ExternalProductImage.ExternalImageId  = Product.ExternalImageId
                                  INNER JOIN ProductImageAngle as ExternalProductImageAngle ON
                                      ExternalProductImage.AngleId = ExternalProductImageAngle.Id
                                  WHERE HasImage=1
                                  GROUP BY Product.Id
                              ) as ByExternalImageId ON
                                  ByExternalImageId.ProductId = Product.Id
                                  WHERE COALESCE(ByExternalImageId.ProductImageProviderId,EANProductImage.ProductImageProviderId) IS NOT NULL
                                  ) as images INNER JOIN ProductImageProvider ON ProductImageProvider.Id = images.ProductImageProviderId where Name='GS1'
-- The original query ends --
                                  )
AS SubqueryAlias ON SubqueryAlias.ProductID=Product.Id
)AS SubqueryAlias ON SubqueryAlias.ExternalImageId=ProductImage.ExternalImageId
```

I put comments to highlight the original query. I added a sub-query (`SELECT Product.Name, Product.Description ,SubqueryAlias.*  FROM Product inner join`) in order to have two more columns. Everything went alright. However, for the second sub-query,

`AS SubqueryAlias ON SubqueryAlias.ExternalImageId=ProductImage.ExternalImageId` returns an error saying:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
>
> Invalid column name 'ExternalImageId'.

This is probably because, in comparison to the other sub-query, `ExternalImageId` is not declared in the original query, whereas, `ProductId` is. Because of my limited SQL knowledge, I can't really figure out what is happening in the original query and especially can't figure out how to fix the code so that I will be able to get `ProductImage.Brandname` and `ProductImage.Description` by joining the `dbo.ProductImage` table with the original query on `ExternalImageId`.

Comment: Knowing the line number that error is relevant to would be great... `ExternalImageId` appears 10 times on 7 different lines. That error could be in regards to any of them. Does the error say it's on Line 7, 12, 22, 27, 28, 29 or 34?

Comment: Otherwise give us the DDL of your tables, so that we can at least replicate the error.

Comment: My bad. The error occurs on: `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 32`, meaning that the problem is occurring here: `AS SubqueryAlias ON SubqueryAlias.ExternalImageId=ProductImage.ExternalImageId`.

Comment: All those nested queries make it incredibly difficult to understand, I'm sure some could be replaced by straight joins or Common Table Expressions. Why don't you start afresh for this query rather than re-using an already complicated query. Oh and you have two nested queries both called SubQueryAlias!!!!

Comment: @SteveFord Long story short; I have been given a task at my internship place which had that complicated query already written. In order to go continue with the task, I would really need these columns added all together. The reason why I don't re-write it is because, in the first place, I would need to know what actually happens inside the query. My expertise regarding SQL is low as I am more focused on other languages, but during times like these I think that I should really step up my SQL game. Is there really nothing I can do apart from re-writing that stuff?

Comment: *"The error occurs on.."* Wll, tnhat one is "obvious"; the only 2 columns from returned from the subquery `SubqueryAlias` are called `Product.Name, `ProductDescription`, `images.ProductID` and `images.Name`. There is no column `ExternalImageId`.

Comment: @Questieme you will learn more by rewriting, however you are referencing columns that aren't returned in the select statement of your subqueries and you have 2 subqueries with the same name

Comment: @Larnu Yeah, I realized that. I tried returning the `ExternalImageId` and I kinda failed because of being unsure where exactly to put it. For example, I tried inserting it like this: `SELECT ProductImage.ExternalImageId, Product.Id as ProductId,MIN(EANProductImage.ProductImageProviderId) as ProductImageProviderId FROM Product` on line 9, but I am getting the following error: `Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "ProductImage.ExternalImageId" could not be bound.`. Where exactly should I tell the query to return it?

Comment: @SteveFord Indeed, see above. I tried returning it in different select statements but none of them allowed due to the `The multi-part identifier "ProductImage.ExternalImageId" could not be bound.` error.

Comment: @Questieme I've changed your Sub Query names to be distinct however without knowing where SubqueryAlias.ExternalImageId comes from we wouldn't be able to advise where to add that in your select clause for the join matching to work. From what I can see SubqueryAlias1 (I've numbered them in accordance to first come first served) Would only have columns Product.Name, Product.Description, SubqueryAlias1.ProductId and SubqueryAlias1.Name

Comment: @LinkOps That is also my problem. `ExternalImageId` can be found in the table `ProductImage`. I want to join the columns from BrandName and Description from `ProductImage` on the original query (that huge block of complicated text, as I like to call it) based on the `ExternalImageId` inside it. I don't know if it makes much sense...

Comment: @Questieme That's all good and well but where in SubqueryAlias2 (All but the first and last row of your query) can we get the ExternalImageId field from as it's not referenced anywhere and the table its originally referenced in "ProductImage" Is not a member of the subquery and thus our knowledge of the tables is hindering our abilities to help you getting the joins to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the query has grown a bit complicated, perhaps simplify?

The essence of the query appears to be:

```
SELECT
  IM.Brandname,
  IM.Description,
  PR.Name,
  PR.Description,
  PR.ID as ProductId,
  PR.Name as Provider
FROM  
  Product PR,
  ProductImage IM,
  ProductImageAngle IA,
  ProductImageProvider PP
WHERE Name = 'GS1'
AND   ((PR.ExternalImageId = IM.ExternalImageId) OR (PR.EAN = IM.ExternalImageId))
AND   IM.AngleId = IA.ID
AND   IM.ProductImageProviderId  = PP.ID
AND   HasImage = 1
```

Could you say how this simplified version does not satisfy the requirement?

For example, does it return multiple rows per ID, and if so, what is the desired criteria for selecting the required row.

I already see PR.ExternalImageID is favoured over PR.EAN but it would be easy to make a wrong guess about parts are there for business requirements and which parts are due simply to query syntax.

Also, which table has the 'HasImage' field, I'm guessing it's ProductImageAngle as there appears to be no reason for using that table if not for that. But as I say, there's a lot of scope for wrong guesses in that code.

Note, if the query runs for a long time, you can replace SELECT with SELECT TOP 100 to see the first 100 rows.